# Effective or minimal area of core to calculate losses?

Tags: coil, loss

I've got a problem regarding the information given in coil's datasheet (PQ35/35: http://www.ferroxcube.com/FerroxcubeCorporateReception/datasheet/pq3535.pdf). There are two different areas given: minimal and effective. Which one should I choose to calculate losses?

Comment: Is that a coil that every EE inherently knows about intuitively?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Andy. The core is PQ35/35 and it is characterized by two parameters: effective area and minimum area.

Comment: Closing since the datasheet is needed but not provided.  -1 because this should have been obvious.

Comment: Like Olin says, provide a data sheet link and THAT should have been obvious after my comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just added the data sheet link. The areas are stated on the second page.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "coil", although that's the only resonable way to excite the core but a coil does for sure not require a core. Also, it's not profile, it's area. Please edit this confusing title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum area of the core's cross section can point to a situation where flux density saturation problems can appear if you have too many ampere-turns. Regard this as a potential [bottle-neck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck) point for the magnetic lines of flux.

The effective area of the core's cross section should be used to calculate the inductance for a given number of turns (or use the \$A_L\$ figure instead). This is the proper [figure of merit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_merit) for most inductor calculations: -

[image]

Notice the top two formulas contain the term \$\Sigma\dfrac{l}{A}\$

That term above equals the *effective length of the core* divided by the *effective area of the core* and is portrayed this way because it implies the core is made up from a series smaller lengths (\$l\$) in ratio to the core area for that particular length. It's a way of describing the core shape (in terms of magnetics) as one figure.